# GUI with Web-based languages

Tags: java, android, cordova, user-interface, air

I'm wondering about develop Android and deskopt apps using Web-based languages for the GUI.
I mean, tool like Adobe Air/PhoneGap use HTML and CSS for the GUI and Javascript for the service-side.
Can I use Java for service-side and HTML+CSS for the GUI?

I experienced with develop Android and desktop app using Java (Eclipse) and Adobe Air for desktop app using HTML+CSS. Is there a way/tool to put together all these?

The focus is: Java for service-side, HTML+CSS for GUI, target: Android/desktop app.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Java for server-side and HTML+CSS for client-side.
You can read more [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/html5_front_end_for_an) (Official Oracle Blog post about this topic with source code)